# Ajax Load More Custom Post type WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to load more post calling out the custom post type with the taxonomy array to sort out the specfic post or all Magazine port. If you click Load More and there is no post to return, the user will recieve a message. As of now when I click the "Load More" button, it seems like the funciton just loops with not returning 3 more post.

Below I have written up the steps I have taken to execute WordPress Ajax load more post functionality.

**First Step:**
Created a page template called taxonomy-magazine-category.php that lives in my theme folder with the markup to display 3 post and load more button functionality to return 3 more post at each click until all post are returned.

```
<div class="post row">

    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $latests = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type' => 'magazine',
    ));

    while($latests->have_posts()): $latests->the_post();    //put the post card here ?>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-xl-9">

                <div class="blog-article-cards list-articles">
                    <?php
                        get_template_part('/components/magazine-article-card', null, array( 'magazines' => $magazines[$i], 'style' => 'regular'));
                 ?>
                </div>
        </div>
     <?php  endwhile; ?>

</div>

<script>
    var limit = 3,
        page = 1,
        type = 'latest',
        category = '',
        max_pages_latest = <?php echo $latests->max_num_pages ?>
</script>
<?php if ( $latests->max_num_pages > 1 ){
    echo '<div class="load_more text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-inverse btn-load-more">Load More</a> 
                </div>';
} else { ?>
    <article>
        <h1>Sorry...</h1>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, No Posts Available !'); ?></p>
    </article>

<?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Second Step:**
Developed the function filter snippet of script at the bottom of the functions.php file that lives in /themes/understrap-child. The top function loads the Ajax files in WordPress installation including the custom Ajax file I have created which is in step three. The second function retuns the the post from the ajax handler.

```
function bsubash_load_more_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'loadmore_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'loadmore_script', 'loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'loadmore_script' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','bsubash_load_more_scripts' );


function bsubash_loadmore_ajax_handler(){
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $category = isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category']: '';
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $args['posts_per_page'] =  $_POST['limit'];
    if($type == 'archive'){
        $args['category_name'] = $category;
    }
    query_posts( $args );
    if( have_posts() ) :
        while(have_posts()): the_post();
//write your single post card
            the_title();
            the_excerpt();
        endwhile;
    endif;
    die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore','bsubash_loadmore_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore','bsubash_loadmore_ajax_handler');
```

**Final Step:**
Created an ajax.js file that lives in my theme folder /js/ajax.js which you will see in the funciton at step two. The ajax will not return the post after you click load more including displaying loading and load more static messages. This seems to be working fine.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.btn-load-more').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this),
            data = {
                'action': 'loadmore',
                'limit': limit,
                'page': page,
                'type': type,
                'category': category
            };

        $.ajax({
            url: loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                button.text('Loading...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    $(".latest_posts_wrapper").append(data);
                    page++;
                    button.text('Load More');
                    if (page == max_pages_latest)
                        button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button
                } else {
                    button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**All Done!!!**

**
What is in my template file?**
Above, at the top of my page template, I have other post appearing that are featured post. These post are returning from the proxy. I am just pointing this out so you are aware of what is in my file as well. This isn't impacting my issue.

```
$magazines = [];

$wp_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'Magazine',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'magazine_categories',
                'field' => $categoryId,
                'terms' => $category,
                'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
            )
        ),
    )
);

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

    //$blogProxy = new BlogProxy(get_the_ID());
    $magazine = new Magazine();
    $magazine->title = get_the_title();
    $magazine->featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID());
    $magazine->preview_text = get_the_excerpt();
    $magazine->permalink = get_the_permalink();
    $magazine->date = get_the_date();

    array_push($magazines, $magazine);

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

My goal is to develop a load more button with a custom post type using AJAX. If you follow the steps above you should see an active functionality that doesn't return post after clicking the load more button.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* myloadmore.js */

jQuery(function($){ // use jQuery code inside this to avoid "$ is not defined" error
    $('.misha_loadmore').click(function(){
 
        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
            'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
        };
 
        $.ajax({ // you can also use $.post here
            url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) { 
                    button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().before(data); // insert new posts
                    misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;
 
                    if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page == misha_loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                        button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button
 
                    // you can also fire the "post-load" event here if you use a plugin that requires it
                    // $( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
                } else {
                    button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/* To style the button the according way use CSS below. */

.misha_loadmore{
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 0;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
.misha_loadmore:hover{
    background-color: #767676;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
This is the AJAX handler function. Insert it to your functions.php file.

/* Enqueue jQuery and myloadmore.js. Pass query parameters to the script. */

function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {
 
    global $wp_query; 
 
    // In most cases it is already included on the page and this line can be removed
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 
    // register our main script but do not enqueue it yet
    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );
 
    // now the most interesting part
    // we have to pass parameters to myloadmore.js script but we can get the parameters values only in PHP
    // you can define variables directly in your HTML but I decided that the most proper way is wp_localize_script()
    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // WordPress AJAX
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}
 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );


function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){
 
    // prepare our arguments for the query
    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
 
    // it is always better to use WP_Query but not here
    query_posts( $args );
 
    if( have_posts() ) :
 
        // run the loop
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();
 
            // look into your theme code how the posts are inserted, but you can use your own HTML of course
            // do you remember? - my example is adapted for Twenty Seventeen theme
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
            // for the test purposes comment the line above and uncomment the below one
            // the_title();
 
 
        endwhile;
 
    endif;
    die; // here we exit the script and even no wp_reset_query() required!
}
 
 
 
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. it doesn't seem to be pulling the post once I click on the load more button. It loads but nothing appears. Any solutions?